# Is it possible to configure Android's Monkey test for better web testing ?

Tags: embedded

I am using Android's Monkey application to test web browsing (actually testing the underlying layers, not the browser).
Is there a way to configure the behavior of the monkey besides the throttle parameter ?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Rsf - I think in order to get answers, you'll need to give a couple of examples of something you're having difficulty doing at the moment.