# looking for a way to exercise Android web browser

Tags: selenium, web, embedded

To continue [my monkey question](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/760/is-it-possible-to-configure-androids-monkey-test-for-better-web-testing)
I am looking for a way to generate Web traffic on a device (not emulator) running Android.
The unit under test is not the browser but lower communication layers of the device, so any way to generate simulated web traffic will suffice.
I understand that selenium has an Android version- has anybody used it ?

Comment: why is this a separate question from your original one? I'm confused by your statement that you don't want to test the browser, but lower layers, followed by the request for advice on Selenium - could you give an example of something you want to achieve?

Comment: I am testing a communication stack (hardware, drivers Etc.), we want to test it under real life scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got at least 2 answers:

1. from command line, use `adb`:

   ```
   adb am start "http://http://sqa.stackexchange.com"
   ```
2. from the device itself use an `sl4a` script